# Proof that $\operatorname{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \bar{\mathbb{Q}})\cong\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I heard that $\operatorname{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ is homeomorphic to $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ and so I tried to prove it in the following way:

> We write $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ as the colimit of its finite Galois extensions. Then,
> $$\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \left(\operatorname{colim} L\right)=\operatorname{colim}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} L = \operatorname{colim}\prod_{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}.$$
> It follows that
> $$\operatorname{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \bar{\mathbb{Q}})=\operatorname{Spec}\left(\operatorname{colim}\prod_{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\right)=\lim \coprod_{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})}\operatorname{Spec}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}.$$
> Now, let $F$ be the forgetful functor from schemes to topological spaces. We have
> $$F(\operatorname{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\otimes_\mathbb{Q} \bar{\mathbb{Q}}))=F\left(\lim \coprod_{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})}\operatorname{Spec}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\right)\overset{?}{=}\lim F\left( \coprod_{\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})}\operatorname{Spec}\bar{\mathbb{Q}}\right)=\lim \operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})=\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$$
> since the limits on the categories of topological spaces and of topological groups coincide (as topological spaces, of course). The problem is that I think $F$ does *not* preserve limits.

Can this proof be saved?

(I know that there is a similar proof of this result in the MSE, but would like to understand this one better.)

Comment: Just the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451349/spec-overline-mathbbq-otimes-overline-mathbbq-and-gal-overline-ma?rq=1) to the post you have mentioned.

Comment: $F$ preserves filtered limits of affine morphisms. You can find this in EGA.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg do you happen to know at least in which EGA?

Comment: Sorry, I was too lazy to look it up. But I am glad that you found it by yourself. I would say, finding things in EGA is actually one important (and not so easy) skill when learning algebraic geometry.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Referring to EGA without pages (even volumes) is an example in Serre's [How to write mathematics badly](https://youtu.be/ECQyFzzBHlo?t=259).

Comment: Yeah. It's a comment, not a paper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just posting an answer to close this question.

Martin Brandenburg solved it and the result that he cites, that $F$ preserves filtered limits of affine morphisms, is 8.2.9 in EGA IV.3.